# Issues in google chrome browser with Confirm message script

Tags: javascript

My script to execute in a tab (chrome browser)

```
var popupFlag = confirm(popupMsg);
if (popupFlag) {

  //console.log(timeDiffFlagSuccess);
   } else {
  stopWorker();
  doLogout();
}
```

When we open a new tab in chrome the `else` statement executes surprisingly.

In other browsers, this script works fine.

Comment: If you have checked the "Don't allow this page to show further dialogs" option that appears if you have too many `alert`/`confirm`/`prompt` windows, then it will ignore future calls and immediate return with a negative result.

Comment: Currently in chrome, confirm box comes on screen when I execute this script. Meanwhile , If I open new tab in chrome , script execution goes in else statement and confirm box disappears. So that's the only issue I am getting . I hope this time, I clear the statement